# Synonym Strategy.position_avg_price

Tags: pine-script

I would like to use in my indicator a code that does the same thing as strategy.position_avg_price. When a signal is triggered I would like to know the price

```
indicator("testDMI", shorttitle="TDMI", overlay=true)

lensig = input.int(14, title="ADX Smoothing", minval=1, maxval=50)
len = input.int(14, minval=1, title="DI Length")
up = ta.change(high)
down = -ta.change(low)
plusDM = na(up) ? na : (up > down and up > 0 ? up : 0)
minusDM = na(down) ? na : (down > up and down > 0 ? down : 0)
trur = ta.rma(ta.tr, len)
plus = fixnan(100 * ta.rma(plusDM, len) / trur)
minus = fixnan(100 * ta.rma(minusDM, len) / trur)
sum = plus + minus
med = 100 * ta.rma(math.abs(plus - minus) / (sum == 0 ? 1 : sum), lensig)
sub = plus - med
sig = plus - minus
adx = 100 * ta.rma(math.abs(plus - minus) / (sum == 0 ? 1 : sum), lensig)
Entrylong=sig >=0 
PriceEntrylong=?
```

I tried strategy.positon_avg_price but it doesn't work in the indicator. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

`strategy.position_avg_price` does not return the entry price. It returns your average price in the position. Those are not really the same thing.

If you want to keep track of your entry price, you should save the `close` price or your limit order price in a `var` variable.

Example:

```
var float entry_price = na

entry_price := Entrylong ? close : entry_price
// Set it to na when you exit the position
```